# apollo graphql server privacy control after data is fetched

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server, mern

So , i don't know how to handle this on a graphql service.
I am migrating a service from rest - express api to an apollo api.
my current mongo schema is like this:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: String },
  uid: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  privacy: { type: String, enum: ['everyone','followers','onlyme'], default: 'everyone' },
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

in express environment i used to get post with populated user the then apply a privacy control function based on user followers.

but in apollo i cant access post after its populated . where can i apply a directive or something after the post fields is resolved?

graphql schema:

```
type User {
    _id: ID!  
    name: String
    followers: [ID]
}

type Post {
    _id: ID!  
    title: String!
    body:String
    uid :User @privacy
}

extend type Query{
    post(_id: String):Post
    posts:[Post]

}
```

post resolver:

```
{
    Query: {
    post: (p, a, ctx, info) => {
      return ctx.modules.post.getPost(a._id)
    }
  },
  Post: {
    uid: (p, a, ctx, info) => {
      return ctx.modules.user.getUser(p.uid);
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do that inside your resolver?

Comment: yes because post resolver does not  have populated `uid` field wich is needs by the privacy function , unless i fetch it twice in the `post resolver` and in the `uid resolver`